# Xamarin .Net Remoting exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-remoting

I'm doing a project where i need to connect an android (Xamarin) to a server.
When I execute the invocation for the remote object on the client side (Xamarin), it generates an exception.

When I execute the same code on the server side, doing a remote invocation to itself, no exception is generated, so I conclude that the problem must be from Xamarin.

Code executed:

```
            IInHomeServer client = (IInHomeServer)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IInHomeServer), "tcp://localhost:8080/InHome");

            client.switchLight("test", 4.0);
```

this code just changes the text on a textbox for testing purposes..

```
{System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-   x86/etc/mono/2.1/machine.config".
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x001e2] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:233 
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, System.String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:152 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions,string,bool,bool,bool)
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) [0x00065] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs:255 
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs:236 
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs:207 
 at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs:184 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.LoadDefaultDelayedChannels () [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting/RemotingConfiguration.cs:147 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.CreateClientChannelSinkChain (System.String url, System.Object remoteChannelData, System.String& objectUri) [0x00092] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels/ChannelServices.cs:113 
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetClientChannelSinkChain (System.String url, System.Object channelData, System.String& objectUri) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting/RemotingServices.cs:683 
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetOrCreateClientIdentity (System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef objRef, System.Type proxyType, System.Object& clientProxy) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting/RemotingServices.cs:639 
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetRemoteObject (System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef objRef, System.Type proxyType) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting/RemotingServices.cs:750 
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.Connect (System.Type classToProxy, System.String url) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting/RemotingServices.cs:193 
 at System.Activator.GetObject (System.Type type, System.String url) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:350 
 at App1.MainActivity+<>c.b__0_0 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00002] in C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHubVisualStudio\InHome\MainActivity.cs:34 }
```

Can anyone help me?
Tagged: android c# Xamarin .NET Library

Comment: "localhost" on a Android device or emulator refers to the device/emulator itself, not the local machine.

Comment: @Jason I've tried to use the IP that the VS emulator presents (169.254.80.80) but no change.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen remoting used in a Xamarin app.  I know it's not supported on iOS - I have no idea if it will work on Android.

Comment: Have you tried this with linking set to "Don't Link"

Comment: @RobertN how do i set the linking?

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: @RobertN I can't find that option in Visual Studio

Comment: I find that option for the object which is written for Xamarin (user) and linking was already none. The server which is regular c# doesn't have that option.

Comment: I only meant the Xam side as it will remove code without a strong static reference...

Comment: ok. I also tried to create the path it referes in the C: drive (Users/...) but still doesn't work. Is there any way to set incode the location of machine.conf file?

Comment: There is nothing like machine.config on Xamarin side of things. Take is as a c# wrapper for actual Android SDKs if you want to understand what it can do for you. .NET Remoting in itself is heavily reflection and code emit (to some extent) based technique and as that would not work correctly (for sure not on IOS). I would suggest you to drop the .NET remoting approach here, and write a mobile server RESTFUL service instead and connect as usual, using HttpClient and JSON req/resp. A pain, but in the long run, better solution anyway.

Comment: And, if you require binary and are in need of lightning speed communication, there is always protocol buffers ready to be used as your API. Highly recommended this one.